# Send a javascript var to php via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to call a variable from a script via ajax on an onclick but the values are not being sent. This is where the variable is being declared, the ajax function and the php of how im calling it with the POST method. The value is not sending or it says undefined coord.

```
var c = function(pos){
            var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
            var long = pos.coords.longitude;
            window.coords = lat + ', ' + long;
            window.url = 'https://maps.google.com?q=' + coords + '&z=60&output=embed';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
            $("get_location").click(function(){
                var coord = $(this).attr('coords');
                $.ajax({
            url:"save.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {coord:coord},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
                })
            })
        })


SAVE.PHP FILE
echo($coords = (isset($_POST['coord'])));
```

Comment: `$("get_location")` won't find any elements, I guess you mean `$(".get_location")` or `$("#get_location")`

Comment: @Machavity, the `this` looks fine, in jQuery event listeners it always refers to the element the event was triggered on. The only obvious problem here is the selector.

Comment: @RobinZigmond i fixed the $("#get_location") but it still wont send the value to save.php

Comment: @Machavity I see where my error is, but i dont really know how to call the function since its inside variable c. I would really appreciate your help with this

Comment: You could modify your function to store the value in a div elsewhere on the page as well as drawing the map using it, and have that div styled to not be visible. Then it would be easy to retrieve the value. A little clunky, but would probably work.

Comment: And does the element have a `co-ords` attribute? Because your Ajax request is sending the value of that attribute. You can see in your developer tools exactly what data is being sent, and what response is received from your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I notice immediately:

1. Your `get_location` element appears to be missing either a dot `.` prefix (if you're referencing it by class name) or a hash `#` (if you're referencing it by id). If you add your HTML to the question, I would be better able to diagnose if that's the issue.
2. If `get_location` is being incorrectly referenced *and* there is no attribute called `coords` where your latitude and longitude are defined, then yes, it makes sense that it is `undefined`. The [`.attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function in jQuery is intended to get/set the value of an attribute from/on an HTML element. Your HTML would need to look something more like this:

```html
<!-- if referencing by id, use $('#get_location') -->
<div id="get_location" coords="12.12345,45.45678" />

<!-- or, if referencing by class, use $('.get_location') -->
<div class="get_location" coords="12.12345,45.45678" />
```